# My vip variable does not take False as a value and always defaults to True

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, queue, priority-queue

Below is the code to return either a VIP customer or an ordinary customer, the list does not take vip as a False value and always takes True.

```
Class DonutQueue():
    def arrive(self,name,VIP):

        self.name = name
        self.vip = VIP
        if self.vip==True:
            self.queue2.append(self.name)
            return self.queue2
        else:
            self.queue.append(self.name)
            return self.queue


    def next_customer(self):

        while not self.queue2== []:
            if not self.queue2==[]:
                return self.queue
            else:
                return self.queue2

def main():

    n = int(input("Enter the number of customers you want to add"))
    for i in range(0,n):
        name = input("Enter their name")
        vip= bool(input("Are they a VIP"))
        DonutQueue.arrive(name,VIP)
    print (DonutQueue().next_customer())
```

Below is the output:

```
Enter the number of customers you want to add2
Enter their name John
Are they a VIP False
Enter their name Wick
Are they a VIP True
None
```

Why am I getting None as the output and my value always takes True when I input False.

Below is the debugger values:

```
i:0
n:2
name: John
vip: True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `input()` method reads user input and returns it as string.

Python `bool()` will always return a `True` value for a non-empty string and **`False` only if a string is empty**.

In order to get correct the value for vip as a `bool` you have to manually check the input string

```py
vipString = input("Are they a VIP")
vip = True if vipString == 'yes' else False
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Python are case sensitive. Therefore, when you assign the input to `vip`, it is never used and `VIP` is used instead.

```
vip= bool(input("Are they a VIP"))
DonutQueue.arrive(name, vip) #instead of VIP
```